# Dynamically creating the navigation tab, one active and other not

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I would like to dynamically create navigation tab. 
First element in the tab should contain active class and rest all should not. How to achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="o{{gridTeams[$index].name}}">
    <div class="tabbable">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href=
                    "#c{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}">Data{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id=
            "c{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <table class="table table-stripped" style=
                    "width: 500px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name</td>

                                <td>test-ns120-01</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to remove active class from this line in next iteration, so that only one tab should remain active.

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="#c{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}">
    Data{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Uh, you may want to show the code you are using to dynamically create this html...

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<script>
            $(function () {
                $('#id').addClass("active");
            }
            );
  </script>
Pass the id of the li that you want to make active.
</pre>
```

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.